# Always show mobile version in safari OS X

Tags: macos, safari

I do not know where to public my question and in fact i hope that it is the right place :)

I really like mobile version of one web site, but at the same time i hate full version of it. Is it possible to make redirect in safari on my OS X? Possible do you know some extensions, tips and etc.

I checked ip adresses of that two version and they are the same. So i cannot just edit the hosts file.. Hope you know a solution. Thank you.

Comment: There is no toggle on the website? Some website check the user-agent (if you know what this is?) to display the full site or mobile version. Others don't, so there is no option to force mobile site that way.

Comment: There is no toggle on website. That web site check the user-agent and if in safari to choose iPad user-agent it will show mobile version, but it is not possible to save my choice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [enable the Develop menu of Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html#developer), then you can choose your user agent.

Comment: Yes, it is working but it does not save that settings..

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way than clicking your way through pull down menus. I'm a big fan of key commands, so if you go to *System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts* pane, go to the *App Shortcuts* side menu item, pick Safari from a list of apps and then add a new short cut.

Use this specific text: *Safari iOS 7 — iPad* and then set up a key command to bring up the iOS version of the website. My preference is to use command-options-shift-i to bring up the iOS version of the site and then if I want to toggle back I have another set up to trigger the menu text *Safari 8.0*.

I find this particularly helpful for view sites that want to force you to use flash video (which I abhor and have disabled in the browser with plugins) to load HTML5 video. This is also good if you want to download video for later viewing when you may not have adequate internet access. It also lets you automatically cherry-pick the highest available resolution by default when you download.

Hopefully this helps.